# slow load testing with Gatling

Tags: scala, gatling

I'm using Gatling for load testing, when I'm trying to post a batch of my objects every second for longer period of time.
It works as I want where there is 100 objects in a JSON array, however, the time increases with larger batches (1000 objects - around 5 seconds between requests, 2000 objects - around 10 seconds between requests, etc...).

I'm wondering what is the issue, my environment is capable of handling such amount of data, in the Gatling output I have response time lower than 1 second.

I'm using csv feeder with the csv file around 3.6gb, so my gut tells it may somehow connected. The data is preprocessed, each cell in csv file is a json array later used as a request body.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you checked your bandwidth usage? Aren't you saturating your NIC/network?

Comment: I'm using internal network, there is no issue here. It seems the issue is with reading cell from CSV file, some of the cells have up to 8mb, depending on the batch size configuration.

Comment: Honestly, such humongous parsing and allocations are hardly compatible with performance.

Comment: Requirements... The system should be able to handle 4000 objects per second. The Gatling is supposed to proof that.

Comment: 4,000 objects by second

Comment: 1 request with large body, per second